# Deque iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

I have a bounded buffer in my code to move data between a producer thread and a consumer thread.
This is what the buffer looks like

```
template <class T> 
class BoundedBuffer {
private:
    std::queue<T> buffer;
    int capacity;
    std::size_t bufferSize; // helps when despositing thread deposits at a lower rate than the fetching thread fetches

    std::mutex lock;

    std::condition_variable not_full;
    std::condition_variable not_empty;

public:
    BoundedBuffer(int capacity) : capacity(capacity), bufferSize(0) {}

    void deposit(T data)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(lock);
        // Wait if buffer full
        bool bWait = not_full.wait_for(l, std::chrono::seconds(3), [this] {return buffer.size() != capacity; });

        if (bWait)
        {
            buffer.push(data);
            not_empty.notify_one();
        }
    }

    T fetch()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(lock);
        // Wait if buffer empty
        not_empty.wait(l, [this]() {return ((buffer.size() != 0) && (buffer.size() > bufferSize)); });

        T result = buffer.back();
        buffer.pop();
        bufferSize = buffer.size();      

        not_full.notify_one();

        return result;
    }
};
```

The producer thread `deposit`s and the consumer thread `fetch`es. This had been working as expected for me, but recently sometimes I get the following error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\deque
Line: 505

Expression: deque iterators incompatible

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
Project.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

I believe the breakpoint is triggered on the line `buffer.pop();` because after the project breaks the next line is highlighted to run.

I checked the contents of the buffer after the program breaks, the buffer is not empty. I saw that the zeroth element of the zeroth element of the buffer cannot be read by the debugger, which may mean that it is corrupted but I don't understand why as I only run into this error after my code has been running for a few minutes and the buffer has been in use multiple times already. The `T`ype of the buffer in my case is `std::vector<ImagePtr>` where `ImagePtr` is a user-defined type from a closed-source SDK.
What's causing this error and how can I resolve it?

UPDATE: I'm not too sure but the problem may have been that the `ImagePtr` image was getting released in the producer thread after being `deposit`ed each time. I guess if the image was released before it was `pop`ped, that's what was triggering the error. Since I've stopped releasing the image I haven't encountered this error again.

Comment: @drescherjm `buffer.pop();` causes the error. I've edited my question to update

Comment: I believe your queue is somehow empty. I would add an assert(!buffer.empty()); before the back().

Comment: @drescherjm the queue is not empty. However I think that the zeroth element may be corrupted

Comment: Is there a chance that your BoundedBuffer was freed?

Comment: @drescherjm I don't think it gets freed. After breaking, I can see the contents of the buffer, the size is usually around 10 and all other elements except the zeroth element of the buffer are intact in memory.